# ctypes and string

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I have a simple C-file:

```
char* initializetest() {
    char * test = malloc(1000);
    return test;
}

int searchtest( char* test )
{
   strcpy(test,"test");
   return 0;
}

main()
 {
    char *test = initializetest();
    searchtest(test);
    printf("%s\n", test );
}
```

and python file:

```
from ctypes import *

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.test_library=CDLL("test.so")
        self.test_initialize = self.test_library.initializetest
        self.test_search = self.test_library.searchtest
        self.test_search.restype=c_int
        self.m = self.test_initialize()

    def search(self):
        self.test_search(self.m)
        print self.m

r = Test()
print r.search()
```

How to get "test" string in python ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
from ctypes import *

charptr = POINTER(c_char)

test = CDLL('test.so')
test.initializetest.argtypes = []
test.initializetest.restype = charptr
test.searchtest.argtypes = [charptr]
test.searchtest.restype = c_int

buf = test.initializetest()
test.searchtest(buf)
print cast(buf, c_char_p).value
# TODO Release the "buf" memory or it will leak.
```

**EDIT**

Initially I used `c_char_p` to pass the buffer between the functions but `c_char_p` is like a const pointer. If used as a `restype`, you will actually get a Python `str` back. So for `initializetest` it will create a string from the allocated memory (by copying data) and throw the pointer away.

Now we're creating a new type, a `POINTER` to `c_char`. This is then used in both functions.

For Python, this type points to a single char so we have to cast it to get the whole string after `searchtest` is done. We cast to `c_char_p` because we just want to read the value so a const pointer is OK.

As a side note, this illustrates the disastrous effect of using `c_char_p` with functions that modify the array (as `searchtest` above does):

```
>>> libc.memset.argtypes = [c_char_p, c_int, c_int]
>>> foo = 'Python'
>>> foo
'Python'
>>> libc.memset(foo, ord('x'), 3)
44808532
>>> foo
'xxxhon'
>>>
```

Note how we've managed to change an immutable Python string!

The `argtypes` setup line isn't even needed because `ctypes` assumes `c_char_p` if Python `str` is used as argument.

Comment: You're right, it didn't work. I've edited the answer. Note that your fix could lead to a segfault.

Comment: @yak why could that code lead to a segfault ? I think I'm hitting my head against that case

Answer (score 1):

Maybe by using restype like [described here](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#return-types)

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.test_library=CDLL("./test.so")
        self.test_initialize = self.test_library.initializetest
        self.test_initialize.argtypes = []
        self.test_initialize.restype = c_char_p # c_char_p is a pointer to a string
        self.test_search = self.test_library.searchtest
        self.test_search.restype = c_int
        self.test_search.argtypes = [c_char_p]
        self.m = c_char_p(self.test_initialize())

    def search(self):
        return self.test_search(self.m).value

r = Test()
print r.search()
```

EDIT: corrected after test :)